# Boost build fails with "failed common.mkdir build"

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build Boost 1.77 using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on Windows 10:

- I download file boost_1_77_0.zip and uncompress it.
- I open an "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" and cd to the boost_1_77_0 directory.
- I run bootstrap.
- I run b2...

  .\b2 --build-dir=build/x86 address-model=32 architecture=x86 toolset=msvc-14.1 --build-type=complete stage

...this fails and in file boost_1_77_0\build\x86\boost\bin.v2\config.log I have:

```
...found 20 targets...
...updating 16 targets...

        if not exist "build\\" mkdir "build"
    
...failed common.mkdir build...
...skipped build\x86 for lack of build...
...skipped build\x86\boost for lack of build\x86...

[snip]

...skipped build\x86\boost\bin.v2\check\predef\msvc-14.1\release\address-model-32\architecture-x86\runtime-link-static\threading-multi for lack of build\x86\boost\bin.v2\check\predef\msvc-14.1\release\address-model-32\architecture-x86\runtime-link-static...
...skipped <pbuild\x86\boost\bin.v2\check\predef\msvc-14.1\release\address-model-32\architecture-x86\runtime-link-static\threading-multi>predef_check_cc_09a06289f4560e2f553bb0cbbec71436.obj for lack of build\x86\boost\bin.v2\check\predef\msvc-14.1\release\address-model-32\architecture-x86\runtime-link-static\threading-multi...
...skipped 3 targets...
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
config-cache.write build\x86\boost\bin.v2\project-cache.jam
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.

    type "C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Local\Temp\jam5298fccb.000" > "build\x86\boost\bin.v2\project-cache.jam"

...failed config-cache.write build\x86\boost\bin.v2\project-cache.jam...
...failed updating 1 target...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I see that error about group policy but I can't find the root cause of it.  When I execute that "type" command at the command line it completes successfully.

**Edit**: I found a solution which I posted below as an answer.  Stackoverflow forbids me from marking that answer as accepted because my account is not old enough.

Comment: `...failed common.mkdir build...` Looks like it can't create its desired build dir. Have you tried creating build\x86\boost for gits and shiggles to see if that works?
Might be a permissions issue

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me!  I found a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Something within the bowels of the boost build system is attempting to do something for which I lack the necessary permissions.  The workaround was to launch a command window from within Visual Studio (rather than from the windows start menu) and invoke the build from there.  The organization is forced to allow VS to run with elevated permissions, and these are inherited by the command window, which then allows the boost build to succeed.